# Typo in moderator inbox, "new announcments"

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, spelling

Possibly a typo in sentence (should be "announc**e**ments"):

> Moderator inbox (new announcments)

Found as a source string in transifex/traducir: https://ru.traducir.win/strings/12478